# SQL Server database update query in Winforms

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYDrO.jpg)I am writing the update query but it doesn't work. When I run this code, nothing is updated in my database table.
My connection string is

```
public partial class cutomers : Form
{
    public static string connection = 
         @"Data Source=HOME-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=WATER-Supply;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);

    private void update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();

        string UPDATE = "UPDATE Customer_db SET Cust_Phone = @cusphone, Cust_Email = @cusemail, Cust_Address = @cusaddress WHERE Cust_Name = @cusname";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(UPDATE, con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cusname", cusname.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cusphone", cusphone.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cusemail", cusemail.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cusaddress", cusaddress.Text);

        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Customer Update...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us your **connection string**?

Comment: i am already use my databse table connection at top,see                                 
        public partial class cutomers : Form
    {
        public static string connection = @"Data Source=HOME-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=WATER-Supply;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: `MessageBox` will do nothing (at best)  and `Form` is not part of ASP.Net... Could you please check tags you've added to the post?

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the right database to check the values...

Comment: Connection string and UPDATE query look fine - silly question: are you using a `@cusname` value that just simply doesn't exist in your table? Then of course, nothing would be updated. Also: what value do you get back `.ExecuteNonQuery()` - the value of `i` after the call - what is it??

Comment: i am use same code to insert values in table it work ,but when use to update not work

Comment: You haven't answered my question: **what** is the value of `i` after the `.ExecuteNonQuery()` call ?? If the `cusname.Text` textbox where you enter the customer name contains e.g. a trailing space, there will not be a match - and `i` should be 0. Matching on strings is always rather tricky.....

Comment: Also: what is the **structure** of your SQL Server table? What are the columns and what is their datatype??

Comment: sorry sir iam copy that field from net which you asked me - i after .ExecuteNonQuery()

Answer (score 0):

I created a console application and I was able to update with the following code. What is the value returned by: command.ExecuteNonQuery()?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UpdateCustomerCommand(Guid.Parse("77ceef70-ab98-4392-835d-66c9face5f16"), "John Doe", "johndoe@acme.com");
    }

    public static string connectionString = @"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=labdb;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";

    private static void UpdateCustomerCommand(Guid Id, string name, string email)
    {
        var updateCommand = "UPDATE [Customer] SET [Name] = @NAME, [EMAIL] = @EMAIL WHERE [Id] = @ID";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
                   connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(updateCommand, connection);
            command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
            command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = Id;
            command.Parameters.Add("@NAME", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 150);
            command.Parameters["@NAME"].Value = name;
            command.Parameters.Add("@EMAIL", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
            command.Parameters["@EMAIL"].Value = email;
            command.Connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you sir i will try this code, then i will reply you